# Transition a div on changing a boolean value

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, css-transitions

I'm changing mode of a card using a boolean `editMode`. now when `editMode === true` some content appears in the **child div** which gives **parent div** more height and width. I want to give transition to this expansion of **parent div** when editMode equals to `true`. I'm working on vue.js.

**How can I do this ?**

```
<div class="parent">
    <h2> Card Title </h2>
    <div class="child" v-if="editMode">
        some content including inputs, labels, ...
    <div>
    <button @onClick="editMode = !editMode"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What issue you are facing ?

Comment: Hi @CreativeLearner In examples like this (https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition2) the transition triggers with a hover or activation of a button or div. My problem is that how can I trigger it using a boolean variable?

Comment: I added an answer. Hope that will help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this question by using vuetify-transitions. The problem was the parent dive itself was in another wrapper component and I could solve it by giving the wrapper transitions.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    editMode: true
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="parent">
    <h2> Card Title </h2>
    <transition name="fade" :css="true">
      <div class="child" v-if="editMode">
          some content including inputs, labels, ...
      </div>
    </transition>
    <button v-on:click="editMode = !editMode">Click Me!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Terry, Looks like you commented on this answer by mistake. I did not asked the question.

Comment: My bad. However, I don't see how this is different from OP's code?

Comment: @CreativeLearner Where is the transition in this code? I can not understand how this is solving my problem.

Comment: @aliforooghie, I updated the answer. Hope it will help! Thanks.

Comment: First of all, thank you for you answer @CreativeLearner. The problem with this is answer is that the whole div does not involves with the transition. I want to give transition to "parent" component not the child since there are more than one child div in the parent component.

Comment: @aliforooghie you can make the changes accordingly. I just gave the example of the solution of the problem you mentioned in question.